# Office 365 Proplus-word Equation Tools does not work properly

Tags: office365, equation-editor

I hope here is the right place to ask this question!

I used to work with Equation Tools in Office 365 Proplus. Rcently, I noticed some of its features do not work properly. Just to provide some examples, when I type "a^2" it does not change to "power of two," minus sign looks like a dash, and Equation Tools' pane that provide access to symbols and mathematics operators appear one-by-one and with a delay! As another issue, when I press the space button, it leaves the equation and jumps to the next line!

[A screenshot that shows some of the issues explained above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOIe7.jpg)

I first tried to repair Office but it did not solve the issue.
I then uninstalled and reinstalled the Office, but it did not help, maybe because the software is keeping some registry information.

How I can repair this problem? Or how can I make a COMPLETE uninstall before installing the app again?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to change Equation Tools setting under the Design option (see the screenshot below). Choose "/Unicode" and this solves the issue.

[Equation Tools setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSbBb.png)

Regarding other parts of the question:

2. To repair Word: You could learn more details from this article: [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)
3. To Complete uninstall Word. You could use [Easy Fix](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8) to complete uninstall word.

Comment: This is the answer I received from Microsoft Agent | Moderator, Jonk Li. It solved my issue. Thanks to Jonk and Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

To insert equation in Word 2016, try the following steps:

1. Click Insert, in the **Symbols** group, click **Equation**.
2. In the **Equation Tools**, click **Script**, select **Superscript** to insert.
   [image]
3. Type a and 2 to related position.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I need to use keyboard shortcuts, as I explained above, to write the equations, which is fast and efficient.